# Вставка массива в файл

Tags: массивы, php, файлы

Здравствуйте.

Есть файл, в котором написано:

```
<?
$test = array(
1=>"Блок 1",
2=>"Блок 2",
3=>"Блок 3",
4=>"Блок 4",
5=>"Блок 5"
)
?>
```

Он подключен через include.  
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно его изменить и записать обратно в файл?  
Проблемы в самом выводе массива в таком виде, print_r() вывод в похожем виде, но без `"`, и именно выводит, а не возвращает строку.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно!